# Bad publish() / process() interaction in Java Swing

Tags: java, swing, swingworker

I'm programming an online videogame in java. I've already done the server and now I'm onto the client.
My problem lies somewhere in the socket listener code, a swingworker subclass whose job is to listen to the server (doInBackGround()) and update the game map as necessary.

Here's the code:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.List;

public class GameWorker extends SwingWorker<Void, String> {

    private SocketStreamsBean streams;
    private GameFrame game;

    public GameWorker(SocketStreamsBean streams, GameFrame game) {
        this.streams = streams;
        this.game = game;
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground() throws Exception {
        for(String msg = streams.getIn().readLine(); msg != null; msg = streams.getIn().readLine()){
            System.out.println("bp "  + msg + " " + Thread.currentThread().getId());//TODO remove
            publish(msg);
            System.out.println("ap "  + msg + " " + Thread.currentThread().getId());//TODO remove
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void process(List<String> list) {

        for(String msg = list.remove(0); list.size() != 0; msg = list.remove(0)) {
            System.out.println("dp "  + msg + " " + Thread.currentThread().getId());//TODO remove
            String[] cmds = msg.split(":");
            switch (cmds[0]) {
                case "ADD":
                    game.add(cmds[1], cmds[2], cmds[3]);
                    break;
                case "MOVE":
                    game.remove(cmds[1]);
                    game.add(cmds[1], cmds[2], cmds[3]);
                    break;
                case "REMOVE":
                    game.remove(cmds[1]);
                    break;
                case "BULLETS":
                    //game.addBullets(cmds[1]);
            }
        }
        list.clear();
    }
}
```

According to the three debug println() when a player moves and the server broadcast it to all the clients the message is read and published but never processed. How could it be?

Comment: Don't remove from the list within the process method. Simply iterate and handle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are removing messages from the list twice in `for` loop - `list.remove(0)`:

```
for(String msg = list.remove(0); list.size() != 0; msg = list.remove(0))
```

Here is a simple way to iterate a list:

```
for(String msg : list){
    System.out.println(msg);
}
```

Comment: I really can't understand how the two things are related but it actually worked, thank you!

Comment: @StefanoBerti you are welcome! You were removing messages from the list before even having a chance to process them. There is no need to remove/update the list at all. Just iterate the list. I hope it helps to clarify it a little :)